# Can/ Why can't I read a text file into my Kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy

Im making a game app that involves, reading a text file. The app doesn't seem to work when I do this. I erased the code that read the text file and simulated just a snippet of information that the text file would have and the app worked fine.
Here is the code I want to use

```
textfile = open('symbols.txt', 'r') 
symbols = textfile.read()
textfile.close()

symbols = symbols.split('\n')
```

Where `symbols` is a list of words I wish to use

Comment: This should work. Post more details about how it fails, e.g. the traceback if it crashes.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Mac, and for some reason It doesn't give me tracebacks